# GT.M - Compiler in Direct mode

Tags: mumps

I'm working with GT.M source code and read this information in mumps.hlp file :

> ZCOMpile
>
> The ZCOMPILE command invokes the GT.M compiler from within the GT.M
>   run-time environment.
>
> Within GT.M itself, ZCOMPILE provides the functionality of the
>   mumps    command, except for mumps -direct.

So...which compiler to be using in "mumps -direct" mode , which file store source code for this compiler ?
I mean that ,when you type :

`GTM> SET ^FOO="BAR"`

Which compiler responsible for compiling that command

Answer (score 2):

Ryo,

It's compiled in memory. It's not stored in any file.

--Sam

Comment: Thank for your answer .but I think it's also need a compiler to compiling commands which user input in direct mode  ,isn't it ? .What are responsible to doing that ?

Comment: I don't know where it happens in GT.M source code; the mumps binary builds an AST in memory of your source, compiles it and places the result in another area of memory; and then it's handed over to the runtime to run. All of this happens in C; except that part of the runtime is in assembler. If you have lots if time, you can read dm_mode.c.

Comment: Thanks, I need to know that because I want write a module which catch all user input command for analysis purpose and security . I mean that when you type : `SET ^FOO="BAR"`, I can catch this command and if you don't have role to do `SET` on `FOO`,I will intercept it and throw an error about Access denied permission

Comment: Anw , I could not found dm_mode.c in GT.M source ,does it appear in other program ?

Comment: Quoting from memory gets me in trouble again. It's dm_read.c.

Comment: thank you ,this file is useful for me now ! , great answer